# Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I'm trying to build an application that uses Microsoft Graph to automatically create and read pages in OneNotes stored in SharePoint 365.

I can successfully do this using Graph Explorer as long as I am logged in, but can't get it to work using a bearer token in Postman

The error I am getting is:
**Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token**

I successfully get an access token using this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

And passing in the grant_type, client_id, client_secret, code, redirect_uri and scope

Then I perform the following call, with the bearer token included in the header:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites
```

With the following getting returned:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AccessDenied",
        "message": "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "fa442c72-4ffe-493b-a33a-8e9e78c94f09",
            "date": "2018-01-19T09:56:34"
        }
    }
}
```

I have set up graph permissions as per below. I have also tried enabling ALL Notes permissions configured with the same result though
[Graph Permissions Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYQND.png)

One post I found said to check http://jwt.calebb.net/ what is returned in the token, and I found that it doesn't contain any roles, so I wonder if this is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried making a call to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks, like in the graph explorer?

Comment: Not possible. I'm not connecting to a user endpoint so /me just throws an error stating as such

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I think I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: Oh, I got it, I had a v1 App but I was trying to call the v2 OAuth endpoint.  Also I was using Sharepoint permissions, when i was supposed to be using Site permissions in Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token using when application permissions to read sharepoint sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526395/either-scp-or-roles-claim-need-to-be-present-in-the-token-using-when-application)

Answer (score 4):

You may need to state your tenant in the url when getting the token :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Thanks to Tsuyoshi Matsuzaki as seen here :  [How to use Application Permission with Azure AD v2](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/)

> Your application can get access token using the following HTTP request
>   (OAuth). Note that you cannot use
>   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` (which is
>   commonly used) for getting the token. Instead, you must use
>   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, which
>   identifies the specific tenant.

Comment: This was not clear in the documentation, so thanks for calling it out.

Answer (score 1):

The call that you mentioned "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites" is not valid.
Also request to ~/sites/... routes may need other permissions in addition to Notes.ReadWrite.

Recommend to follow steps mentioned in the following references:

1. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference
2. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user
3. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Comment: So the auth is working and I'm receiving an auth token as per link #3 (#2 is irrelevant in my case). I had read link #1 before but re-reading it seems like I might need to use the /user/{id}/notes endpoint and just pass the Id of a service account that can access all the notebooks I need. I'll try that and mark answer once confirmed

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't work. When I try to connect to /users/{id}/notes, it tries to take me to onedrive data, but these are stored on sharepoint. There doesn't appear to be a /users/{id]/sites endpoint to go down that route

Comment: I've also tried adding Sites.Read.All, with no luck

Comment: First, the path /users/{id}/notes is incorrect. It should be /users/{id}/onenote. If your notebook is on SharePoint and you know the site id, you can use GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/onenote/notebooks. The site id looks like the composite id that is returned from GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root kind of query with comma separated values

Comment: I tried the call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/companyname.sharepoint.com,11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111111111,11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111111111/onenote/notebooks. With that, I get "OneDrive for Business is not provisioned for this user". Which is odd because my token should be for application permissions, not user permissions

Comment: Can you share the client-request-id and the timestamp in the response headers that you got back? Thanks!

Comment: "request-id": "b5ad59af-ae78-4611-b296-0dc257165e60", 
"date": "2018-01-24T11:25:13"

Comment: This particular request failed because the sites Id is incorrect. Can you check your sites Id again?