# Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token using when application permissions to read sharepoint sites

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I created an app in Azure and set it up to use Access and ID tokens.

[image]

I want to connect to different tenants and read SharePoint sites. Here are the permissions I've requested and received Admin Consent for:

[image]

For now, I have set up an App Secret but I do plan to move to a certificate later.

I have this code to get the access token and I do get an access token back:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
params.append("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
params.append("client_id", process.env.client_id);
params.append("client_secret", process.env.client_secret);

var url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
const response = await fetch(url,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: params,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }
);
```

However when I try to read the root site below

```js
var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*";
const response = await fetch(url,
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}` }
    }
);
```

I get this error:

```js
error: { 
    code: 'AccessDenied',
    message: 'Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.',
    innerError: { 
        'request-id': 'ec47913f-2624-4d1c-9b27-5baf05ccebfd',
        date: '2019-08-16T14: 15: 37'
    }
}
```

I checked the token at https://jwt.io/ and indeed I do not see any entry for `roles` or `scp`.

It looks like I missed a step but I cannot figure out which step.

I am getting the token like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that you cannot receive both Application and Delegated permissions in the same token, it is an either/or scenario. Which type you receive depends entirely on which OAuth Grant you used to request the token:

- Authorization Code and Implicit return Delegated tokens with an `scp` property
- Client Credentials return Application tokens with a `roles` property

The second thing is that you've requested scopes to two different APIs. Based on what you've selected, you won't have access to SharePoint through the Microsoft Graph because you've only requested access to the legacy SharePoint API. More importantly, you've only requested the Delegated `User.Read` scope for Graph so when you use Client Credentials to obtain the token, that token won't have any permissions.

In order to obtain an Application token for reading SharePoint sites, you'll need `Sites.Read.All` [*Microsoft Graph* Application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#sites-permissions) selected.

Comment: Thanks Marc! The delegated permission is added when you create a new app which I thought was needed so I didn't delete it. Deleting that delegated permission and adding User.Read.All Application permission and granting admin consent has fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi Marc, you mentioned "You won't have access to SharePoint through the Microsoft Graph because you've only requested access to the legacy SharePoint API". I see one option for SharePoint under Request API Permissions. So did I select the correct option?

Comment: You want the `Sites.Read.All` permission under "Microsoft Graph", not the `Sites.Read.All` under "SharePoint".

Comment: Thanks Marc! That did the trick. Setting **Sites.Read.All** under "Microsoft Graph" allows you to search for sites and enumerate sub-sites under a site.