# Why is this "AccessDenied" while Communicating with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I cant access endpoints in Microsoft graph.

I will be uploading a file to a users one drive when I have the communication set up
but for now I am just trying to get a list of items in a drive.

This is the response I get from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{drive_id}}/root/children

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": "AccessDenied",
  "message": "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.",
  "innerError": {
  "request-id": "123",
    "date": "2020-01-09T11:43:20"
  }
 }
}
```

I retrieved the drive_id by using graph explorer on endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
on the signed in user.

It should be noted that I can use this endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
So I must be doing something right with the access token.

I followed [this](http://codematters.tech/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oauth-rest-api/) tutorial to get the access token using the client credential flow.

and this is the code I use to get the access token

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www- 
 form-urlencoded"));
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token");
            req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
                {"client_id", "123"},
                {"client_secret", "123"},
                {"resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com"}
            });
```

When I decode the JWT I do not see any scopes in the token but if I understand correctly  
header should get the scopes that have been permitted by admin.

An admin has already granted my app these permissions for graph explorer:
(Although I do not have the delegate permissions, does that matter?)

```
Filse.Read,
Files.ReadWriteAll,
Sites.ReadWtiteAll,
User.Read
```

I am using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman) collection in postman to test.

Thanks in advance any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token using when application permissions to read sharepoint sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526395/either-scp-or-roles-claim-need-to-be-present-in-the-token-using-when-application)

Answer (score 2):

**From Marc LaFleurs' answer :**

*The first thing to understand is that you cannot receive both Application and Delegated permissions in the same token, it is an either/or scenario. Which type you receive depends entirely on which OAuth Grant you used to request the token:*

*Authorization Code and Implicit return Delegated tokens with an scp property
Client Credentials return Application tokens with a roles property
The second thing is that you've requested scopes to two different APIs. Based on what you've selected, you won't have access to SharePoint through the Microsoft Graph because you've only requested access to the legacy SharePoint API. More importantly, you've only requested the Delegated User.Read scope for Graph so when you use Client Credentials to obtain the token, that token won't have any permissions.*

*In order to obtain an Application token for reading SharePoint sites, you'll need Sites.Read.All [Microsoft Graph Application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#sites-permissions) selected.*

Comment: This question has come up enough that I wrote up some details a while back. This might also prove helpful: https://massivescale.com/application-vs-delegated-scopes/